# What are equivalents to R's "phyper" function in Python?

Tags: python, statistics

In R, I use the `phyper` function to do a hypergeometric test for bioinformatics analysis. However I use a lot of Python code and using rpy2 here is quite slow. So, I started looking for alternatives. It seemed that `scipy.stats.hypergeom` had something similar.

Currently, I call `phyper` like this:

```
pvalue <- 1-phyper(45, 92, 7518, 1329)
```

where 45 is the number of selected items having the property of interest, 92 the number of total items having the property, 7518 the number of non selected items not having the property, and 1329 the total number of selected items.

In R, this yields `6.92113e-13`.

Attempting to do the same with `scipy.stats.hypergeom` however yields a completely different result (notice, the numbers are swapped because the function accepts numbers in a different way):

```
import scipy.stats as stats   
pvalue = 1-stats.hypergeom.cdf(45, 7518, 92. 1329)
print pvalue
```

However this returns -7.3450134863151106e-12, which makes little sense. Notice that I've tested this on other data and I had little issues (same precision up to the 4th decimal, which is enough for me).

So it boils down to these possibilities:

1. I'm using the wrong function for the job (or wrong parameters)
2. There's a bug in scipy

In case of "1", are there other alternatives to `phyper` that can be used in Python?

EDIT: As the comments have noted, this is a bug in scipy, fixed in git master.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.7.x/reference/generated/scipy.stats.hypergeom.html), you could try:

> `hypergeom.sf(x,M,n,N,loc=0)` :
>   survival function (1-cdf — sometimes
>   more accurate)

Also, I think you might have the values mixed up.

> Models drawing objects from a bin. M
>   is total number of objects, n is total
>   number of Type I objects. RV counts
>   number of Type I objects in N drawn
>   without replacement from population.

Therefore, by my reading: `x=q`, `M=n+m`, `n=m`, `N=k`.

So I would try:

```
stats.hypergeom.sf(45,(92+7518),92,1329)
```

Comment: Still gives a negative p-value, but since the other tests I did are comparable, I wonder if there isn't any side effect I'm not aware of.

Comment: I think its a bug in scipy: http://biostar.stackexchange.com/questions/9746/which-way-to-calculate-cumulative-hypergeometric-distribution-is-more-accurate

Comment: @Einar Looks like this issue has been fixed recently: http://projects.scipy.org/scipy/ticket/1218 Try updating your scipy installation

Comment: Noticed the commit, I'm building from git master to see whether the issue is fixed. EDIT: Indeed, it is fixed in master.

Comment: I also set this as the correct question because indeed I also made a mistake in calling sf, so with this I fixed the issue completely. Thanks.